# excel vba udf custom help macrooptions conditional based upon argument values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user-defined function in VBA to calculate unit conversions from input units to output units. The function accepts four arguments:

- measurement type (e.g. "Mass", "Temperature", "Pressure", etc.)
- input units (e.g. "kg", "°C", etc.)
- output units (e.g. "lbm", "°F", etc.)
- input value (numerical value in input units)

I am familiar with using the MacroOptions method to assign custom help text, but I am curious if there is a way to change the help text based upon the value of an argument. For instance, if the user specifies "Mass" as the measurement type, is it possible for the input units argument help text to only show mass related units (e.g. kg, gram, lbm, etc.)?

If this is possible I would assume that I would need to catch events from the "Function Arguments" form that is presented to users in order to enter arguments. Any tips on catching events from that form?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: I don't think that is possible, although I can't find a good reference one way or the other.  One option includes creating a different function for each type of measurement.  You could have those handful of functions all call the same underlying function (like C# overloading).

Comment: Does the native CONVERT function not do what you need?

Comment: Byron, thanks for the comment. I may end up using the approach you suggest if I cannot find an alternate solution. However, the goal was to make the tool general purpose so that users could define additional measurement types and they would be immediately useful.  Rory, the CONVERT function is useful, but does not support all of the units or dimensions that I would like to support.